# How to create a User - Group model in rails? with muliple authorization enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

A user could create a "group", which other users could join in. Each group has its own admin and moderators so on and could do something like creating posts, inviting users, etc.

I think "has_many through" should be used here, but not sure about the authorization, since the role is based on different groups. The roles set up in CanCan seem not fit into it, admin is just for one group, not the whole site.

Comment: You have to create role like `user.is_admin_of?(GroupObject)` so first step is create role 
For this you can use https://github.com/timonv/rollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like confusion between a user and its role.
A "Group" has many "users". A "user" has one (or more) "role(s)" (admin) toward a group "ALPHA". A "user" might have another role ("listener") on another group "DELTA".

Admin is a role, Moderator and listener are roles just the same.

Comment: And how can I use CanCan to limit the group to certain degree? I've read the wiki, but unable to write it on my own. Is there any other examples?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create role like user.is_admin_of?(GroupObject) so first step is create role https://github.com/timonv/rollable